# Visual studio can't find file

Tags: fonts, visual-studio-2012, sticky-notes

I'm trying to revert Sticky Notes back to Segoe UI (I don't even know how it ceased to be in that font in the first place) so I'm trying to edit C:\Windows\System32\en-US\StikyNot.exe.mui o Visual Studio since that appears to be the answer from my research but VS doesn't find it. The "open file" dialog on VS doesn't show the file although it's selected to show all files (*.*) then I've managed to open to try to open the file itself by VS through "open with" through a registry fix but as soon as VS opens it shows the message:

```
The following lines were specified in the command line:
     C:\Windows\System32\en-USStikyNot.exe.mui

These files could not be found and will not be loaded.
```

Any workaround for getting Segoe back to Sticky Notes would be nice. The current font - which I couldn't identify - can't even be used in a big size without being distorted to the point of being unreadable (Look at what happens when I try to use a font that's bigger than that very small size of the 2nd note). I'm on Win 8 x64

https://i.stack.imgur.com/tpQfq.jpg

Answer (score 0):

No, VS will not help. Try this (found on http://splittingmythoughtsinto2.blogspot.com/2013/03/change-sticky-notes-fonts-style.html#.UjSGYX-bHTo):

- Run - type regedit
- Navigate to: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Fonts
- Find "Segoe Print (TrueType)" and"Segoe Print Bold (TrueType)" on the Right Panel
- Change the value (double click on font) to the file name of any other font that you wish to use that is already installed. Change both fonts one by one.(For "times new roman" use times.ttf. For Arial font, its arial_0.ttf  and for Arial Bold, its arialbd_0.ttf)
- Restart the computer.

Comment: My Sticky Notes isn't using Segoe, it's using some random horrible font. Look at what happens when I try to use a font that's bigger than that very small size of the 2nd note (I put it in my edited question)